# Inject external properties for Apache Storm Flux

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-flux

I am using Flux 1.0.0 and I have rewritten my topology into a YAML file. But I have some properties that used to be part of the configuration that I used the Storm driver to run with.

`storm.Driver --config myConfig/config.conf`

Now with Storm Flux, how can I inject the properties that are in `config.conf` into my topology?

I am currently doing `java -cp myStormJar org.apache.sotrm.flux.Flux --local /src/main/resources/myTopology.yaml`

I tried to use `--resources` option, followed by the path to the conf file, but it does not inject it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the filter --resources placeholders `${resource.filter}` to your yaml file.
To make the property available in the `stormConf` - re-declare the filter resource in `config:` properties.

```
name: "storm-topology"

config:
    kafka.mapper.zkPort: ${kafka.mapper.zkPort}
    kafka.mapper.zkServers: ${kafka.mapper.zkServers}
```

You can also review the simple_hdfs.yaml example at: https://github.com/ptgoetz/flux/tree/master/flux-examples